# how to show child element in right panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi can you please tell me how show child element in right element .My function work fine first time But it fail second time .

I do the following steps

1) Press Add button 2 times.Generate row2 as well as submenu of firstLevel.
2) Expand menu option (+) Button.Click "menu_tc_1".It remove rows on right panel .and press add button it create nested submenu .

3) When you press again "menu_tc_1" it show same number of rows as many you click add button.

4) But when you click "First Level " it should show two rows because it have two child("menu_tc_1","menu_tc_2") .It is showing  all rows.Because in array it gives all values.

I need show only child 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZR7N/17/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li > a', function (e) {
    //first method..
    console.log($(this).siblings().length);

    var selEl = [];
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function (idx, el) {
        var id= el.id.replace('menu_','');
        selEl.push(id);
    });

    // alert(id);
    console.log('aaa' + selEl);
    getViewFromPanel(selEl);
});

function getViewFromPanel(arr) {
    console.log(arr); 
    $('#ultest').html('');
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $('#ultest').append('<li id=' + arr[i] + '><a href="#" class="foo">' + arr[i] + '</a></li>'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you building? Your JQ seems pretty scary big for what I think you need.

Comment: nested tree..In left panel

Comment: It will show same no of rows as same number of child.If you press two time add button it should show two rows

Comment: I think you should first build a program that works, show us the only needed code, and than implement animations and fancy stuff... It's totally incomprehensible, you click on ADD you create elements, if you click them again they disappear, but if you click inside the panel suddenly you have them back! Wow :) that's why I'm asking. Never seen something like that and I was wondering what's the final product?

Comment: Sir I am not doing animation..I just use child concept .I am making view of right panel using left panel

Comment: I just want to show child of (+) button if it have 3 then it show 3 rows .It is showing all childs of  (+) button .Mean if (+) button have 2 child .But one of child also (+) button.It is showing all childs of (+) button also which is also nested

Answer (score 0):

See **[this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZR7N/18/)**.

The main problem is `$(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function (idx, el) {`. `find` will look for all sub levels, that is why is displays all menus. You only want the children of the next ul:

```
$(this).closest('li').children('ul').children().each(function (idx, el) {
```

Also, you skip the first element (probably due to using find) in `getViewFromPanel` - it should start at 0 index:

```
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
```

There is a problem with the way that you set the active class so when you go back and click add, it is added to the wrong hierarchy. I am not sure what your intention is with the active class, but I think that you should clear the class `$('.active').removeClass('active')` and set it again when the hierarchy changes.